# Grafana and PostgreSQL: extract hour from timestamp in Browser-Time timezone when db saves in UTC

Tags: postgresql, grafana

Fabrics at different locations in the world are working in shifts and I want to do calculations per shift but I have a problem - the timestamps. I don't understand them.

in db they are in UTC
in grafana in Local Time/Browser Time

first shift starts at 05:00h till 13:00h local time
second shift starts at 13:00h till 21:00h local time

I wouldn't know the offset from UTC so I can manually move the shift start and end time.

What I think could help me achieve aggregation by shift is if I assign the shift number to a row. In this case, what I want to do is to take the offset from UTC from Browser Time setting in grafana time filter.

my approach that got me the problem:

```
WITH base AS (

  SELECT "Timestamp" AS time,
          extract('hour' FROM to_timestamp("Timestamp"/1000)) AS h,
          [some_metric]
  FROM [table]
  WHERE $__unixEpochFilter("Timestamp"/1000)
 
      
), shifts AS (

  SELECT *,
    CASE
      WHEN (h >= 5 AND h < 13 ) THEN 1
      WHEN (h = 13 AND h >= 21) THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END AS shift_nr
   FROM base
)

-- what I want to be able to do in the end   
SELECT shift_nr,  avg([some_metric])
FROM shifts
GROUP BY shift_nr
```

[image]

as you can see from intermediate (`select * from shifts`) output
column **time** is ok - following grafana time zone settings - Browser time
column **h** is ok by itself because it reflects UTC in db - but this not what I want. I want to extract the hour from **time** column but no matter how I rewrite the query I always extract the UTC time.
column **shift_nr** is not ok - it should say shift 1 instead of 3

This is the only approach I was able to think of. Most likely there is an easier one - I read a lot of threads and none seems to be applicable/work for me.
If you think of another approach - please enlighten me!
If you know how I could assign a shift number to a row based on shift start(05h,13h) and end(13h,22h) in their respective local time when the timestamp in db is saved in UTC but the time settings in grafana are Browser time - please do tell.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: "*I wouldn't know the offset from UTC*" - that seems to be the actual problem. For any solution, you *must* know the timezone of the particular factory. There's no way around that.

Comment: I understand. I also have my suspicions that it is too much of a wish there to be a way to extract the time zone from the browser through postgresql in grafana. Thank you for writing!  :)